# How to get dynamic templates to load from file ES 2.3.1

Tags: elasticsearch

Good afternoon. I have recently been working on updating our ELK stack and have been having issues with dynamic templates once I have upgraded to ES 2.3.1. I am working on Debian Ubuntu system, I have my template defined in a file under /etc/elasticsearch/templates.

```
{
  "template_1" : {
    "template" : "*",
    "mappings" : {
      "_default_" : {
        "dynamic_templates" : [
          {
            "geoip-location" : {
              "path_match" : "geoip.location",
              "mapping" : {
                "type" : "geo_point"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "geoip-ip" : {
              "path_match" : "geoip.ip",
              "mapping" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "norms" : { "enabled" : false }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "level-string" : {
              "match" : "level",
              "mapping" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "norms" : { "enabled" : false }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "line-string" : {
              "match" : "line",
              "mapping" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "norms" : { "enabled" : false }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "validanswers" : {
              "match" : "validanswers",
              "mapping" : {
                "enabled" : false
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "jobid" : {
              "match" : "context.jobid",
              "mapping" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "norms" : {"enabled" : false }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my previous version 1.7.1 this worked fine and I was even able to use it to reindex all of my old indexes. I would like to keep this as an external file if at all possible.

Thank you,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible anymore, since 2.0.0. It's a breaking change documented in the ES documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/breaking_20_index_api_changes.html#_file_based_index_templates). There is no replacement, you should use the `_template` API.

Comment: Thank you @AndreiStefan! Can't believe I didn't find that on the website. I scoured the web for hours. As a follow up question, is there a way to import a file using the _template API? This may just be a lack of understanding on my part using the CURL statement. Again thank you!

Comment: Actually I figured the CURL statement out. Again Thank you to @AndreiStefan